# Стоит ли выносить api-классы в отдельный пакет api?

Tags: java, spring, шаблоны-проектирования

Я разрабатываю приложение, которое само по себе несет функционал и имеет кучу классов с логикой. Но мое приложение так же будет использоваться в качестве библиотеки, поскольку для него будет возможность создать плагин. Я сделал api-классы, которые разработчики плагинов смогут использовать. Стоит ли все такие классы вынести в отдельный пакет api? Или это нормально, что api классы будут в общей куче классов с логикой?

Comment: А что мешает сделать это?

Comment: незнание, нормально ли это

Comment: Незнание не является проблемой, лень - это уже проблема.